# How to have your app send email confirmation when user registers

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am following a video that uses Intent.ACTION_SEND but when I run my app and register on it, I don't find any emails from my app. I just want to execute a simple task. User types their email address, then clicks a button, which will send an email confirmation to the email that the user typed. Here's my code:

```
Intent sendingEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendingEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email.getText().toString().trim()});
        sendingEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendingEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        sendingEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendingEmail, "Testing..."));
```

Comment: Have you tried with `sendingEmail.setType("text/plain");`?

Comment: Didn't work. but looking at the logcat it said that no activity found to handle intent. @instanceof

Comment: Oh I remember now, you probably don't have any email applications on your device, right? So if that's the case, install one, like Gmail, and try again. Also, if this is the case, you might need to check if the user also has a email app installed, otherwise it will also crash on the user's device.

Comment: The thing is i'm not trying to have the user open any email applications. I'm trying to have my app send an email once the user has sign up, saying welcome to this app... Like if i would've signed up for facebook or whatever, it would say to go to my email and check for an email from them. @instanceof

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure if that is possible, but maybe someone around here knows? Otherwise you could write a very small php script to send an email, host it somewhere, and then call it from the app when the user clicks the button...

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping anyways :) @instanceof